# django inline within same model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have following model defined,

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Translation(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
```

now i want to achieve such an admin interface where i can enter multiple `languges` to translate a common `field_name`, that is ,i want to avoid entering `field_name` each time to translate it in different languages.

**for an example** if i want to translate `banner`(which is a field name) in multiple `languages`(which is foreign field) at a time,then i want to enter `banner` for a single time and then choose multiple languages from different rows and save.Can it be possible without changing my current model structure? According to current structure of my model, i have to enter `field_name` each time(though field name is same) to translate it in several languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your foreign key field to many to many field as it defines your requirement in more appropriate manner.

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
```